# java - making sure only one thread initializes object

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a small issue with making sure initialization of the object is done by one thread and only once i.e. given below code snippet:

```
AtomicBoolean initialize = new AtomicBoolean();
CountDownLoatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

void init(){
     if(initialize.compareAndSwap(false,true)) { 
          someMethod() // this can throw some exception
          latch.countDown();
      }
      else{
          latch.await();
      }
}
```

I could wrap the countdown in finally block as now the thread mnight get stuck if exception happens. However, even with finally block, the thread will get released and the system will be in an uninitiatlized state. Is there a pattern to follow to get this right?

Comment: Well what do you want the behaviour to be if `someMethod()` throws an exception? Should another thread be able to have another try?

Comment: synchronize on the block of initialization .

Comment: is it a static block ? if not do different thread be calling this code from different objects?

Comment: In either case, the other thread does not know anything about the error in the other thread - I would have to store it in some volatile/atomic variable and then either retry/fail I guess..

Comment: Would other threads need access to this object as well, assuming it was initialized properly by that one thread? If yes, this looks like a job for Singleton, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to start with a simple and correct solution. If performance really matters, you can optimize it afterwards. A simple solution might look as follows:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
private boolean initialized = false;

void init() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (!initialized) {
            someMethod();
            initialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If performance matters, you can add an additional check of the boolean variable, that uses a *volatile* variable instead of a synchronized block. This pattern is known as *double-checked locking*:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
private volatile boolean initialized = false;

void init() {
    if (!initialized) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (!initialized) {
                someMethod();
                initialized = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do something like:

```
private static boolean initialized = false;

public synchronized void init() {
  if(initialized){return}
  if(initialize.compareAndSwap(false,true)) { 
      someMethod() // this can throw some exception
      latch.countDown();
  }
  else{
      latch.await();
  }
  initialized = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you might want to use the "initialization on demand holder idiom"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Initialization_On_Demand_Holder_Idiom

Answer (score 0):

A lock free method of initializing state can be using an AtomicReference holding the state:

```
private static AtomicReference<Object> LAZY_INITIALIZED = new AtomicReference<>();

public static Object getLazyInitialized() {
    Object result = LAZY_INITIALIZED.get();
    if (result != null)
        return result;
    result = new Object(...); // all initialization takes place here
    if (LAZY_INITIALIZED.compareAndSet(null, result)) {
        return result;
    } else {
        // another thread beat us to it, throw away our state and use the
        // state that finished construction first
        return LAZY_INITIALIZED.get();
    }
}
```

Note that this *doesn't* really ensure that there is only one copy of the state created, it only ensures that only *one copy of the state is ever handed out*. If that is absolutely not acceptable, you will need some sort of synchronization to protect the construction phase, like shown in the answer using a synchronized block.

An alternate method is *eager initialization* (that requires the least effort and has excellent access performance):

```
   private static final EAGER_INITIALIZED = new Object(...);

   public static getState() {
       return EAGER_INITIALIZED;
   }
```

The reason you might want to keep the getter here is that you can change your mind later to use another idiom.

Comment: in my example nothign will use the state until the thread that initializes calls latch.countdown and signals to other threads that it is done